# Why haven't I got sockpuppet hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I finally wrote an answer to old, old question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/98150/16495). I was sure it entitles me to get a Sockpuppet hat, as the requirement is "answer your own question". But I didn't get it. I did get a Ho Ho Ho hat for this very answer, so it is not a case of hat script not noticing.

Comment: FYI ho ho ho for vote on 25th December, happy Christmas!!!!!!!!!!!!! molot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just answering is not enough - but question and answer must be upvoted (presumably during the bash).

The more detailed description of the requirement is: "ask and answer your own question, each with a score of 1 or more".